# remove dollar symbol using regsub

Tags: tcl

Right now my $arg returns a money value. for eg: $65.88

Now I am trying to remove the dollar sign because I want do some calculations on that .
variable.
the following does not work. it still returns  a value with the $ sign preceded.

```
regsub -all {$} $arg {} arg
```

Comment: $ usually means end of line - escape the $ and all should be well

Comment: regsub -all "\$" $hd_rate "" $hd_rate something like this?

Comment: see my edit to my answer (and http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regsub.htm#M13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$ usually means end of line - escape the $ and all should be well

[edit]

```
regsub -all {\$} $arg {} arg
```

[/edit]

Comment: regsub -all "\$" $arg "" arg
 puts "$arg" ..this still returns me the value with the $ preceded

Comment: this may require more investigation, my answer is generic for reg expressions

Comment: You either need to use curly braces, or you need to ecape your escapes. Backslash is special for both double quotes and regular expressions

Answer (score 5):

You don't need regular expressions for this task. Use `string map` to replace the dollar sign with the empty string, or search for The dollar sign and then remove it with string commands.

Regular expressions are good, but if you don't understand them and just use an expression you got off of the internet, you've just created software that you may have a hard time maintaining.

Comment: The specific transform would be: `set arg [string map {$ {}} $arg]`